# Removing NSNotification in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

So I have a VC that i register for a notification in viewDidAppear:  Even when the VC is not the main focus, as when I push another VC on the stack, I still want that VC to receive the notification.  But after that VC is no longer needed, i.e. it is popped off the stack, I want to remove it as an observer for that notification.

Where do I do that?  viewDid/WillUnload: are no more, and i tried dealloc, but it never gets called.  So this seems to mean that the NotificaitonCenter will retain the VC, and it will never get released when it is popped off the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `dealloc` method. That is the established convention nowadays.

The NotificationCenter is not retaining the VC. Where did you get that impression?

Comment: because when i pop the controller off of the navigation stack, and send out the notification, my controller object is still around and receiving it.

Comment: How do you know? Did you check via instruments? If yes, reconsider your architecture if you do not want the VC around anymore. Something else might be keeping hold of it. Fix the problem by proper architecture, not by working around the way NSNotifications work.

Comment: yes, i agree completely.  i just have to figure out why this thing is still around.  just started looking into this...

Comment: Per the docs:   The block to be executed when the notification is received.

The block is copied by the notification center and (the copy) held until the observer registration is removed.    I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that the VC would be held as well.  It's a probable crash if the VC is gone and the Center still tries to execute the block.

Comment: You should use a "weak self" in blocks. That way blocks will not hold a a strong reference to the class in which they originated.

Comment: @mickm You possibly have a strong retain cycle. Are there `UIView` properties that you are adding to the view which are declared as `strong`?

Comment: yes, right about weak self, wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: Nikita, not sure, been too busy typing here to get back and try to figure this out... :-)

Comment: missed a reference to self in the block.  replaced it with the weak pointer, and all is well.

Comment: Then as a courtesy, please accept my answer as definitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in the `dealloc` method of the `UIViewController`

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

If you are using Swift then you can put it in the `deinit` method of the `UIViewController`

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: that is what i thought.  i have a breakpoint in the dealloc method, and it is never called after the VC is popped off of the navigation stack.

Comment: This means then that something still has a reference to the `ViewController` and so it is not being deallocated. If you post the code your using it might shed some light on the situation.

Comment: posted this below, but.. missed a reference to self in the block. replaced it with the weak pointer, and all is well.

Comment: that will do it every time glad you found the issue and resolved.